# Python, TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: python, tf-idf

```
import numpy as np

def computeTF(wordDict, doc):
    tfDict ={}
    for word, count in wordDict.items():
        if count == 0:
            tfDict = 0
        else:
            tfDict[word] = 1 + np.log2(count)
    return tfDict

tfDoc1 = int(computeTF(wordDict1, doc1))

print (tfDoc1)
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get an error:

> 'TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment'.

Comment: I'm not a fan of Hungarian notation-style naming conventions, but surely `tfDict = 0` should have raised a red flag?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work and will not give you the error. You tried to assign 0 to the dict object rather than adding zero to a dict item.

```
import numpy as np

def computeTF(wordDict, doc):
    tfDict ={}
    for word, count in wordDict.items():
        if count == 0:
            tfDict[word] = 0 #this was wrong
        else:
            tfDict[word] = 1 + np.log2(count)
    return tfDict

tfDoc1 = int(computeTF(wordDict1, doc1))

print (tfDoc1)
```